# gtk3 on macos: window does not restore from the dock

Tags: c, objective-c, macos, gtk3

Using GTK3 on MacOS, after minimizing the window, the dock icon does not restore the window.  I have to use the "Show All Windows" selection from the dock icon menu.

Does anyone have a work-around or know something to make the dock icons work?

I would be happy with some simple objective-c code that would make the dock icons work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void     testBuildUI (void);
gboolean        testMainLoop  (void);

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init (&argc, NULL);
  testBuildUI ();
  testMainLoop ();
  return 0;
}

static void
testBuildUI (void)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  assert (window != NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
testMainLoop (void)
{
  while (1) {
    gtk_main_iteration_do (FALSE);
    while (gtk_events_pending ()) {
      gtk_main_iteration_do (FALSE);
    }
    sleep (1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special code or Objective-C needed if you use `gtk_application_new` instead of `gtk_init` and start your main loop with `g_application_run`.

The documentation states the following:

> Currently, GtkApplication handles GTK+ initialization, application uniqueness, session management, provides some basic scriptability and desktop shell integration by exporting actions and menus and manages a list of toplevel windows whose life-cycle is automatically tied to the life-cycle of your application.

see https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Application.html

**Self contained test program**

Your code slightly adapted to the above points might look like the following:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <assert.h>

static void testBuildUI(GApplication *app, gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("gtk version: %d.%d.%d\n", gtk_major_version, gtk_minor_version, gtk_micro_version);
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("com.example.MyApp",G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(testBuildUI), NULL);
    g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);
    return 0;
}

static void testBuildUI(GApplication *app, gpointer data) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    window = gtk_application_window_new(GTK_APPLICATION(app));
    assert (window != NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));
}
```

If you click on the dock icon of this test program, the window will restore as expected.

**Alternative solution**

If you want to avoid `GApplication/GtkApplication`, you could also use the `gtk-mac-integration` library instead, see https://github.com/jralls/gtk-mac-integration.

The library is rather small, only a few thousand lines of C code, so you can also easily take a look at how it works internally.

There is an important hint:

> Older Gtk applications that aren't based around GApplication can be adapted to use the macOS menu bar and to integrate with the Dock using GtkOSXApplication. The Gtk API that GtkOSXApplication uses is deprecated in Gtk3 and has been removed from Gtk4. Since macOS integration is available directly in Gtk using GApplication GtkOSXIntegration will not be updated for the new menu API and is deprecated. Application maintainers are strongly encouraged to redesign their programs around GApplication, particularly before migrating to Gtk4.

see https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/OSX/Integration

The integration is easy: after `gtk_init` create an application object. After setting up the window call `gtkosx_application_ready` with the application object.

As a side note, there is also a slightly more complex example in the `src` folder called `test-integration.c` under the Github link mentioned above that shows a more advanced menu and dock integration.

Finally, your program only minimally changed to work with the `gtk-mac-integration` lib:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtkosxapplication.h>
#include <assert.h>

static void testBuildUI(void);
static void testMainLoop(void);

static void
testBuildUI(void) {
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    assert (window != NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

void
testMainLoop(void) {
    while (1) {
        gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE);
        while (gtk_events_pending()) {
            gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("gtk version: %d.%d.%d\n", gtk_major_version, gtk_minor_version, gtk_micro_version);
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkosxApplication *theApp = g_object_new(GTKOSX_TYPE_APPLICATION, NULL);
    testBuildUI();
    gtkosx_application_ready(theApp);
    testMainLoop();
    g_object_unref(theApp);
    return 0;
}
```

I installed the library using `brew install gtk-mac-integration` and linked the C program with `libgtkmacintegration-gtk3.dylib`. Also in this variant, the window is restored as expected. when you click on the dock icon of the program.

Comment: I had the "applicaion" stuff in my code at one point, but gtk3 would not work correctly with my code structure.  My application on MacOS was essentially unusable.    All sorts of weird bugs and poor gui performance.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution that completely avoids GApplication/GtkApplication and minimally modified your sample code to work with it. The mentioned library is rather small, so one can take a look at how it works internally.

Comment: The single line:   [NSApp finishLaunching];  make the test program work.   I rather like the icons this mode produces (mini pics of the app in the 'minimized' section of the dock) (and I get these when launching my app from the command line).  Unfortunately, when launching from the .app folder, the icons go into the main section of the dock and are not working.    I wonder if I can get the .app to launch from the command line in the same fashion?  I'll have to dig through that code and see if there any other relevant pieces that will make the dock icons function properly.

Comment: Thanks so much for finding this.  It's going to take a lot of research, but hopefully I can find the pieces I need.

Comment: @StephanSchlect  Actually, my MacOS installation is mucked up and it was running the old code.   The dock icons are working nicely.  Thanks again.